# Session and user authentication using ASP Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, session-timeout

I use Asp Identity for Authentication in MVC project, my problem is the session end and the user still authentication in some cases.

I set the time out of OWIN to 20 min on configuration

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
                SlidingExpiration = false,
            })
```

its work after 20 min my session data and Owin is cleared.

but still problem in some cases :

1. when IIS reset the session clear but the user still authenticated .
2. when I build my solution on vs 2015 the session clear but the user still authenticated .

Comment: have you checked to see if the browser cache has been cleared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie` - cookie authentication.

This is to be expected.. The cookie will live for 20 minutes (as per your configuration) then expire. It has nothing to do with `Session`

If you really want to tie your authentication to a session, see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11420005/131809

I would suggest using an ActionFilter in place of a base class though (as mentionedi n one of the comments)